# Display uptimes on Zabbix screens

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, uptime

I'm struggling to find a proper way to display uptimes on a Zabbix screen.

I have a screen displaying information about each running services health: CPU and memory consumption, and I would like to add the service uptime.

The data itself is correctly gathered, and Zabbix correctly handles the uptime value display on the "Latest data" page and on the associated simple graph.

However I do not find how to display this same data (ie."N days, hh:mm:ss", not "nnnnnnn" seconds) on my screen page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably already tried configuring a "Plain text" screen element. Indeed, there it shows the number of seconds (14756237) instead of the value being formatted as uptime (170 days, 18:57:17). The same issue is when viewing "Values" and "500 latest values" in "Latest data".

There are two workarounds that seem to be available:

1. configure "Simple graph" screen element for that item;
2. put the uptime item into "Uptime" application, for example, and configure "Data overview" screen element to show data for this application; then, it will be formatted correctly.

Comment: Thanks. The data overview worked but seemed quite cluttered for my use case, with all uptimes written on a single array line and service name written vertically. As a workaround, inspired by your answer I made a specific graph uniting all uptimes (+ system uptime), it works quite good. Sad we cannot remove the graph from the graph (!) to keep only the associated legend, and it would miss also a sort feature to get services with lower uptimes at the top to easily catch abnormal things, but I will add this to my todo list as future work if it remains needed in future Zabbix versions.

Comment: By the way, your issue is already being tracked on Zabbix tracker at [ZBX-6638](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-6638).